# How to set object changing limit in Django

Tags: python, django-models, permissions, django-admin

I need to set limit to user on object updating. I mean set permission for user on object (or on some fields) first time Change and View. Second time user have only View permission. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
```

UserPassesTestMixin allow you to do some testing in the controlller

extends this class then implement the next function by adding condition

```
 def test_func(self):    
        if (condition):
            return True
        return False
```